# Delay loaded DLLs are loaded too far away in memory from each other

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll, loadlibrary

I have an x64 Windows application which sometimes crashes within a DLL library which I unfortunately have no control over. This library is actually a large set of inter-dependent DLLs (~40 of them). The crash isn't always in the same place, but here's an example of what is happening:

```
Exception thrown at 0x0000018393916B72 (foo.dll) in bar.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000001831C1F95A0.
```

At this location, the disassembly in Visual Studio shows the following:

```
0000018393916B72  cmp         dword ptr [1831C1F95A0h],3
```

This at first seemed odd to me, since that means the DLL would be hard-coded to load a value at a bad location. So, I took a look at the actual instruction memory and found the following:

```
83 3d 27 2a 8e 88 03
```

Which disassembles exactly to:

```
cmp    DWORD PTR [rip+0xffffffff888e2a27],0x3
```

What's happened here is that an instruction was generated in the DLL which says "Compare the value located X bytes after this instruction to 3." This memory resides in a different DLL from this one, and X is a 32-bit value. I assume that the value of X gets patched when that other DLL is loaded.

Looking at the actual bytes of the instruction, it's clear that it wants rip+0x888e2a27, which does point to where one of the DLLs in this library resides, but unfortunately this 32-bit value gets sign extended and it ends up looking backwards in memory instead of forwards.

Ultimately, the root cause is that these DLLs were loaded into memory more than 0x7FFFFFFF bytes from each other, and thus when they try to reference each other with a 32-bit offset, they fail to do so. I'm unsure why the compiler which generated these DLLs opted to use an RIP+32-bit instruction instead of a 64-bit absolute address, but it seems to have done so quite frequently. Possibly a size-saving measure?

Either way, I figure the easiest way to resolve this issue is to force `LoadLibrary` to load these DLLs next to each other, or at least relatively close to each other. I have tried various way to do this, but it seems Windows is purposefully random and opaque about where it decides to load DLLs.

Is there any way around this problem? Here are my potential solutions, but I don't know how to do any of them:

1. Force `LoadLibrary` to load the DLLs either at a specific address, or with some kind of option which forces these DLLs to be near each other in memory.
2. Modify the DLLs themselves to remove any RIP+(32-bit value) instructions, and replace them with an instruction which supports 64-bit address values.
3. If I could potentially get the vendor to recompile the DLLs, have them use a specific compiler flag to prevent these RIP+(32-bit value) instructions from being used. I don't know what this compiler flag would be, however. I assume they used MSVC but I'm not actually sure.

Comment: What makes you think you should/can directly use specific memory addresses in explicitly loaded DLLs`?

Comment: *I assume that the value of X gets patched when that other DLL is loaded.* - very strong doubt in this. better look in file disasm - what originally was here

Comment: I'm just trying to fix this crash. Loading these DLLs to all be within 31-bit offsets from each other is one way to fix it, but I'd be happy with any solution.

Comment: @RbMm I'm no expert on DLLs, however the value at this location is different every time I run, but always points to the same location within that other DLL.

Comment: absolute sure your crash nothing common with dll load addresses. you are on wrong way. you have absolute address - `018393916B72` - convert it to `RVA` (sub dll load base) and then convert rva to file offset and look what instruction originally here. compare code in memory and on disk at begin

Comment: @RbMM The crash happens intermittently, and only ever happens when these DLLs are loaded more than 0x7FFFFFFF bytes from each other. Next time the crash occurs I will find the info you want and reply again.

Comment: you are on absolute wrong way. crash not depend from dll load addresses. you must not try force LoadLibrary at some base. here something else

Comment: I don't see what distance has to do with this issue.  Whether a library is 32 bytes away or 32k away doesn't make a difference.  However, there may be an issue when using 64-bit addressing and 32-bit addressing.  A 64-bit application can access anything in that 64-bit range.  However, 32-bit library may not be able to *cross* a 32-bit boundary.  Everything that the 32-bit library needs to access should be within the 32-bit boundary, otherwise extended addressing techniques may be employed (successfully or unsucessfully).

Comment: Best guess: in the original code there is some legacy 32 bit pointer arithmetic which was not correctly ported to 64 bit.  With ALSR being integral to Windows security you normally have no control over where a particular module is loaded.

Comment: `cmp dword ptr [1831C1F95A0h],3 ` look like access some global variable - `if (g_x == 3)` - paste several instruction before and after  crash one. convert VA - > RVA -> file offset - look dll disasm. paste original instructions from this file offset. begin from this

Comment: @RichardCritten - *Best guess: in the original code there is some legacy 32 bit pointer arithmetic* - not think. this is or access global variable in code or modified code.

Comment: also possible wrong rip at all - point to random place, due invalid indirect call, or return after damaged return address. for this and need look instructions around and mandatory compare with original code from disk

Comment: @ThomasMatthews 32 bytes or 32k away would be fine. The problem is the two dlls are over 2 billion bytes away from each other, and then using a memory access instruction which uses a signed 32-bit immediate offset from `rip` (instruction pointer). If this offset is more than 2 billion bytes away, then there is no way for this instruction to actually reach the correct location, since the offset from `rip` will be more than what can be stored in a signed 32 bits immediate value.

Comment: The premise sounds fishy.  It's hard to imagine a compiler intentionally concocting a relative reference to code or data that's in a different DLL or executable.  I suspect a corrupted binary or a disassembly that started from a wrong address or just a plain old bug (that's possibly intermittently obscured when the DLLs happend to load closer together).

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy https://godbolt.org/g/JkJ8HF Take a look at the disassembly binary. 83 3d 00 00 00 00 03 disassembles to `cmp    DWORD PTR [rip+0x0],0x3` The 0s are a signed 32-bit immediate value which are an offset from the current instruction pointer. It's then patched by the linker to be the offset to the global variable `g`. So, it's not so hard for me to imagine how this happened.

Comment: @David Clamage:  Your example doesn't cross a DLL boundary.  If I define `g` in a separate DLL, then the code generated to reference it is not a relative offset into the DLL's address range.  Instead, it's an indirect load through the import table, which the loader patches up with an absolute address.  Otherwise, any 32-bit application would run a risk of failure whenever they're executed on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Adding the `__declspec(dllimport)` annotation to g changes the generated code, but not in a meaningful way (still a 32-bit relative load from `rip`). https://godbolt.org/g/R6escg I also have the evidence that this is indeed happening with this set of dlls that are causing me trouble. The dlls do not crash and function perfectly fine as long as they are loaded within "range" of each other. I honestly don't know why this isn't a more common occurrence, but it could be that with my particular application, it happens to occur much more frequently than in other applications.

Comment: @David Clamage:  I'm getting different code from from VS 2017 than Godbolt is showing in your example.  I have `mov rax, qword ptr [__imp_g]; cmp dword ptr [rax],3`.  The __imp_g resolves to an address within the same module, so it doesn't seem to matter where the other module actually loads.  Maybe the app was compiled with a buggy version of VS that's since been fixed.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Could you provide the actual bytecode of the `mov rax` instruction? I'm interested to know if it's still in the rip+X form.

Comment: if `g` is imported from another module it must be defined or as `__declspec(dllimport) int g;` or as `extern int* g` - pointer to `int` but not `int`. in both case asm code will be equal - `mov r,[xxx], cmp r,3` - nothing common with `cmp [xxx],3`. the code `cmp [xxx],3` where `xxx` some hardcoded relative rip offset never can be access of data in another dll, if code generated by linker, but not patched. ant this is of course not *legacy 32 bit pointer arithmetic* (foolishness). you not want listen. show original instructions at this place from dll (on disk). and before and after this one

Comment: The mov is `48 8B 05 9B E8 00 00` and the cmp is `83 38 03`.  The debugger shows that the mov's source address is within the address range of the current module (presumably the import address table).

Comment: Using https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm you can see that `48 8b 05 9b e8 00 00` is `mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0xe89b]` and the `0xe89b` is the last 4 bytes of the instruction in little-endian form. Thus, if this offset ends up >2 billion, there will be problems. EDIT: Ah, I see what you're saying about it being in the current module. So the problem is indeed likely that the global variable from the other DLL is not declared as dllimport. I'll try to investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that this will work, but you could try to edit the DLLs in question with the EDITBIN command so that they are flagged as not supporting ASLR.

The command to do that would be:

`editbin /DYNAMICBASE:NO /HIGHENTROPYVA:NO foo.dll`

Editbin comes with your msvc / windows sdk installations.

For more info, see:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d25ddyfc.aspx

If mandatory ASLR is enabled, the loader will search for a base address for such DLLs starting from the bottom of the address space. So *maybe* that means they end up close enough with each other.

This behavior is explained in:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/srd/2017/11/21/clarifying-the-behavior-of-mandatory-aslr/

The last bit to try would be to load the DLL as early as possbile in the execution of your application so as much as possible of the address space would be free.

Good luck :-).

Comment: I ran this command on all the DLLs for this library, and all of them were untouched except for exactly one of them. I will use this changed DLL and see if the crash continues to occur.